# Iteraring through element of a series in pandas dataframe and updating values based on length of elements

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataFrame having `acctnum,accid,acctsuffix`
In the `acctnum` column some accounts are 16 digit length and some accounts are 15 digit length.

My requirement is to check if `acctnum` length is 16 replace the first digit of `acctnum` to 4 . If length is 15 ,replace the first digit to 3 .

Example, 122122122122122 . Here length is 15 . So it should change to 322122122122122

Let another `acctnum` is 2112112112112112 . Here length is 16. So it should be changed to 4112112112112112

I am trying to write a code. But getting int object is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.str.len` for the lengths, then `np.where`:

```
# make sure that we are working with `str`
df['acctnum'] = df['acctnum'].astype(str)

first_digit = np.where(df['acctnum'].str.len()==15, '3', '4')

df['acctnum'] = first_digit + df['acctnum'].str[1:]
```